# Add row not in table to pivottable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Ok the question sounds weird, the case is the following. I have a pivottable that summarizes how many incidents occured on a day. Howwver, when there's no incident, there's no rows in the table. Is there a way I could add the count of zero to a pivottable? This is my current table:
[image]

Basically I'd like to add a pivot table row with "`2017.10.04    0`" before showing the grand total. Is there a way to do this? I'm currently counting the occurrences of the dates, so I understand this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the summary function:

- Select a cell in the Count of ID column of the pivot table.
- On the Ribbon, under PivotTable Tools, click the Options tab In the
  Active
- Field group, click Field Settings

In the Value Field Settings dialog box, in the list of functions, click on Count Numbers, then click OK

finally pivot table shows a zero or blank cell or an incorrect count.

edit: [How to treat pivot table column names as integer in pivot chart (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758393/how-to-treat-pivot-table-column-names-as-integer-in-pivot-chart-excel)

this link look like show same problem to yours

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand these instructions. There is no row with "2017.10.04" in my data source, so I cannot count it. If I add it and count it, it will be 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

About all you can do is add the 'missing' dates to your data source as a blank row, so that it shows up in the PivotTable.

Comment: The moment I add in "2017.10.04" in my source data, there will be one occurrence of the date "2017.10.04" and thus the count of fields with "2017.10.04" will be 1, not 0.

Comment: Add another column called COUNT into the data source, and put a 1 in it for all items except for the ones you manually added (which get zero), and SUM them.

Comment: Ye  that will solve it, but I was wondering whther you can directly edit the pivot table.

Comment: You can't I'm afraid. Given I've answered your question, can you please consider selecting my answer as the accepted answer.